# jQuery toggleclass for animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, toggleclass

I have been trying to toggle an animation on and off using the .toggleClass. Unfortunately everything works well untill the first animation is complete. The problem is in the remaining animation class on element. I want to completely reset the element's class after applying an animation to it so that when I click on the button again I will not have to double click to remove and run the animation again. I have tried to strip down the animation classes after every animation has been done but have had no success. Somehow removing the class after it has been toggled forces it on the element and I couldn't find a way around it. Basicly, I want to remove the "necessary" double clicking so that I can run the animation again and remove all animation classes toggled on element after the animation has been successful.

Here's the link to jsfiddle.

```
//HTML
<div class="box"></div>
<button class="animationleft">left</button>
<button class="animationright">right</button>

//CSS
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:350px;
    background-color:black;
}
.slideRight {
    -webkit-animation: slideRight 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
.slideLeft {
    -webkit-animation: slideLeft 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideRight{
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  49%  { opacity: 0; margin-left:70%}
  50%  { opacity: 0; margin-left:-70%}
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft{
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  49%  { opacity: 0; margin-left:-70%}
  50%  { opacity: 0; margin-left:70%}
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

$('.animationleft').on('click', function(){
$('.box').toggleClass('slideLeft');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('.slideRight');
    $('.box').removeClass('.slideLeft');
},500);
});

$('.animationright').on('click', function(){
$('.box').toggleClass('slideRight');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.box').removeClass('.slideRight');
    $('.box').removeClass('.slideLeft');
},500);
});
```

Comment: Please make a demo so it will be easier for other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catch with CSS animation is that it doesn't provide a way to re-start your animation unless the animation class is removed then re-applied (which you're doing in your case with limited success) or the animated element itself is re-inserted.

I think the latter would probably give you a cleaner solution. The idea is to remove the box element from the page entirely when the animation is done and re-insert it.

The simple jQuery code routine you can use is as below:

```
var el = $('#box'),  // I switched the 'box' class to an 'id'
    newEl = el.clone(true);   // make a clone of the element
el.before(newEl);   // place the clone
$("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();   // remove the "old" box
```

Here's a working demo (Updated): http://jsfiddle.net/H37CQ/3/

Update #3: http://jsfiddle.net/H37CQ/8/

Comment: Hmm, I like your solution however, my website has two divs that should be animated. I have tried updating the code for two divs but it will not work properly. I'm fairly new to jQuery and I might be missing something really obvious, but here's my jsfiddle that I can't get to work... Thanks a lot for the help! http://jsfiddle.net/H37CQ/1/

Comment: I'd like you to be more clear on what you're trying to accomplish here. I looked at your fiddle and I see two boxes (divs) with only one set of buttons. So, say, if I click the slideleft button, should that move both divs?

Comment: Yes, both divs should move and the classes should be reset after the animation has ended.

Comment: Ok, I see. I tried to complicate it a bit by adding a different animation to the 2nd box. I feel really dumb for asking so many questions, but from what I can see from my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H37CQ/7/ no matter what I click the animation only seems to play to one side and the slideLeftMajica or slideLeftText are not removed. I copied the insertEl function and added the line for copying each text div. I want to apply each box with an animation and after remove the class so that after the animation is done I can just replay the animation with a single click just like in previous fiddles.

Comment: @JonasB Didn't expect to see this many hoops! :)  No need to feel dumb as everyone was at your position at one point. Anyway, here's yet another update: http://jsfiddle.net/H37CQ/8/

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you are expecting is to click your button once, the animation will play, stop, and when you click again - it plays again.

This can be done by capturing *animationend* event , with js code.
Here's a simple example in jquery:

```
$("your-element-selector").addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  //do something here
}, false);
```

BE AWARE that there's also a way to capture transition end event,
BUT you have to remember all prefixed names of the transitions:

```
webkitTransitionEnd
mozTransitionEnd
oTransitionEnd
TransitionEnd
```

Comment: So, in the function I would have to remove the animation class from $(this) if I'm correct?